# How to enable remote JMX connections in Elassandra?

Tags: cassandra, jmx, jconsole, elassandra

I'm trying to enable **JMX** in **Elassandra 5.5.0.4** through `cassandra-evn.sh` file in order to connect to a Cassandra node, **remotely**, and get metrics and statistics.
I'm trying to connect to JMX using **JConsole**.
I have followed various tutorial from datastax and blogs without success.

I tried with and without authentication but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the below parameters are set. The configuration enables JMX metrics remotely without any authentication.

```
# add this if you're having trouble connecting:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public ip>"

LOCAL_JMX=no
JMX_PORT="7199"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Comment: Hi Amin, would you please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506859/monitoring-elassandra-with-prometheus-using-docker/56509434?noredirect=1#comment99687018_56509434) ?