# Monitoring Elassandra with Prometheus using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, elassandra

I'm trying to run jmx-exporter container with special configuration following [this instruction](https://elassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/enterprise.html#monitoring-elassandra-with-prometheus).

I did all the instructions step-by-step. Here is my `docker-compose` file and `conf/config.yml`.

docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - /prometheus:/prometheus
      - ./conf/prome.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command:
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - '6009:9090'

  jmx-exporter:
    image: sscaling/jmx-prometheus-exporter
    container_name: jmx-exporter
    ports:
      - 6011:5556
    depends_on:
       - elassandra

  elassandra:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    container_name: elassandra
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=localhost
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=localhost
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=false
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME='DockerTest Cluster'
      - CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=8
      - CASSANDRA#
      - LOCAL_JMX="no"
      - Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port="7199"
      - Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port="7199"
      - Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port="7199"
      - Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 

      - JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
      - JMX_PORT="7199"
      - JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=5556"
      - JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5556"
      - JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"

volumes:
        prometheus_data: {}
        elassandra_data: {}
```

`conf/config.yml`

```
startDelaySeconds: 0
hostPort: elassandra:7199
#username: 
#password: 
#jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:60/jmxrmi
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
whitelistObjectNames: ["org.apache.cassandra.metrics:*"]
blacklistObjectNames: ["org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ColumnFamily,*"]
rules:
  - pattern: 'org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(\w+), name=(\w+)><>Value: (\d+)'
    name: cassandra_$1_$2
    value: $3
    valueFactor: 0.001
    labels: {}
    help: "Cassandra metric $1 $2"
    type: GAUGE
    attrNameSnakeCase: false
```

whenever I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`, I face with the following page on `localhost:6011`:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to monitor elassandra and its metrics using jmx-exporter, I mainly get the java metrics!

Answer (score 1):

In your config.yml you're using `hostPort: localhost:5556` but you should try to connect to the host `elassandra` (the name of your docker container in your docker-compose.yml file).

Make sure Elassandra is configured properly to allow remote JMX connections. See [How to enable remote JMX connections in Elassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628024/how-to-enable-remote-jmx-connection-in-elassandra) for details how to set that up.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I have updated the post and applied the changes you mentioned. Unfortunately it still doesn't work properly. Would you give us more hints?

Comment: Any errors in the jmx_exporter logs? I see you edited your question to include the ENV variables to expose but they don't seem correct, e.g. `JVM_OPTS` isn;'t properly set in your docker-compose file and `Djava.rmi.server.hostname` seems wrong too.

Comment: I have changed it as you said. but it still doesn't shows the metrics. I don't know how to fix it. I have added a photo to the post and just updated the configuration.

Comment: Your `JVM_OPTS` variables are still wrong (or you didn't update your docker-compose file), take another look at the linked SO page that is linked in the answer.

Comment: I have put them in my docker-compose file but it' still has some errors like `elassandra       | Error: Could not find or load main class "` and Updated my docker-compose in this post. Would you please give me the more detailed solution since I am newbie to Elassandra?